# Why does telnet report "login: -h for super-user only."?

Tags: linux, telnet

I am not able to telnet in to localhost .

```
[root@localhost ~]# telnet localhost
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.localdomain (127.0.0.1).
Escape character is '^]'.
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.5 (Tikanga)
Kernel 2.6.18-194.el5PAE on an i686
login: -h for super-user only.
Connection closed by foreign host.


[root@localhost ~]# su - admin
[admin@localhost ~]$ telnet localhost
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.localdomain (127.0.0.1).
Escape character is '^]'.
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.5 (Tikanga)
Kernel 2.6.18-194.el5PAE on an i686
login: -h for super-user only.
Connection closed by foreign host.
[admin@localhost ~]$
```

What might be the solution ?

Answer (score 2):

In year 2011, the right solution is **[do not use telnet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telnet#Security)**. Switch to [SSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) instead: [enable *sshd*](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/rhel5/rhel5_administration/rhel5_ch-openssh.html), then run `ssh 127.0.0.1`.

---

The *telnetd* daemon on your system is misconfigured: it's supposed to be started as root.

Edit your *inetd* configuration file. For *xinetd*, add `user = root` to the `telnet` service definition; with classic *inetd*, the user is the 5th field in `/etc/inetd.conf`. When done, `pkill -HUP -f inetd`.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add the following line to `xinetd.conf`

```
user=root
```

and then restart xinetd service.